# C# linq adding multiple class into list at once

Tags: c#, list, linq

My question is how to add multiple classes to the list of the class.

```
List<ClassA> _ListClassA = new List<ClassA>();
Enumerablelist.ForEach(x => _ListClassA.Add(new ClassA() { }, new ClassA() { }));
```

See above, I have a list of ClassA. I want to add multiple class objects in the list object using LinQ.

Syntex error it gives is:

```
No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments.
```

I know its wrong way. My question is how to add multiple classes to the list of class at once?

Comment: What you want to achieve? You want to add all `ClassA` in `Enumerablelist` to the existing `_ListClassA`? Or you want to add two `ClassA` instances for each item in `Enumerablelist`? What is `Enumerablelist` at all?

Comment: You rather mean to add multiple objects of `ClassA` to list, right?

Comment: @TimSchmelter No, I want to use one proper of Enumerablelist in _ListClassA.

Comment: @pitersmx yes please.

Comment: Whats is the type of Enumerablelist ?

Comment: I don't understand why to vote down to the genuine question?

Comment: @Maharshi: what means _"I want to use one proper of Enumerablelist in _ListClassA"_? The question is still very unclear, that's why you receive downvotes. Everyone answering here is just making wild guesses

Comment: @TimSchmelter Enumerablelist is also a list of the class having a property which I want to use while adding ClassA into _ListClassA.

Comment: you can use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: @FoggyFinder Yes, I have used addRange and it works fine. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: nice, so you can mark the answer from @pitersmx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your intention right and `Enumerablelist` is of `IEnumerable<ClassA>` type:

```
 _ListClassA.AddRange(Enumerablelist.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

you better use one class dto and define mutti class in dto class

```
public class MyClassDto{
public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
...
    }
```

and use in project

Answer (score 0):

List.Add only has one parameter, you must call it twice.

Example:

```
Enumerablelist.ForEach(
x => 
{
  ListClassA.Add(new ClassA() { });
  ListClassA.Add(new ClassA() { });
}
);
```